# Phonegap Remote Media Streaming Delay

Tags: cordova, stream, external, media, delay

Been searching and not finding a straight answer to this issue.

This is on IOS only

I am using phonegap's media class like this.

```
var src = 'http://www.remotefile.com/test.mp3';
var MusicFile = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);

MusicFile.play();
```

It will play the file around 10-30 seconds later.

It seems that the music file has to go to the external server and completely download the file before it is able to play.  There is no buffering of the audio file being done.

Is this possible using phonegap?

Comment: unforunately this is a bug in the phonegap media , i ended up using html5 audio. so i use phonegap when i play from local and html5 when i play from server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I was starting to think your solution is going to be the only choice.  However I am going to use phonegap media for Android and HTML5 Audio tag for IOS.

Comment: exactly i did the same. phonegap has this bug only for ios and if you open CDVSound.m class you will see a comment there about this issue.

Comment: This shouldn't be the case anymore: since beginning of 2016 I think, `cordova-plugin-media` now correctly reads stream on iOS. It's even faster than on Android, where it looks like it buffers too much before playing the stream.